# Trying to create a web scraper using selenium and beautiful soup

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

Im trying to make a webscraper for a friend that parses through indeed.com to help with job hirings. basically he wants to scrape the page and create a csv file with all job listings including , position, company and job description. Im currently stuck and this is what I have:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
import requests

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://indeed.com')
searchBox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="text-input-what"]')
searchBox.send_keys('Social Media Marketing')

searchButton  = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="whatWhereFormId"]/div[3]/button')
searchButton.click()

import time
time.sleep(5)

popUpButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="popover-x"]/button/svg')
pupUpButton.click()



print(driver.current_url)


r = requests.get(driver.current_url)
print(r.text[0:10500])

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser') 

results = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':'company'})
```

Any suggestions on how I should approach this?

Answer (score 0):

To get job title, company and description, you can use this example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.indeed.com/jobs'
params = {
  'q': 'social media marketing',
  'l': ''
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, params=params).content, 'html.parser')

for title in soup.select('h2.title a'):
    print(title.get_text(strip=True, separator=' '))
    print(title.find_next('span', class_='company').get_text(strip=True))
    print(title.find_next('div', class_='summary').get_text(strip=True, separator=' '))
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Social Media Assistant
iHeartMedia, Inc.
Track social media influence measurements. Minimum of one-year experience with social media or digital marketing ; experience in entertainment or music space…
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Social Media Coordinator (Entertainment)
Valnet Freelance
Good understanding and experience of social media management. As a Social Media Coordinator, you'll be responsible for sparking and maintaining discussions with…
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Social Media / Marketing Coordinator
Five Star Ford Lewisville
Passion for social media and marketing. Developing engagement through all social media avenues. Stay up-to-date with current technologies and trends in social…
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on.
```